# Django Creating User Basics

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django (1.5) and got stucked at assumingly basic stuff. I try to create a User using following code.
VIEW:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def sign_up(request):

    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
        user.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account:login'))

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] = UserCreationForm()

    return render_to_response('account/sign_up.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ACCORDANT TEMPLATE:

```
<html>
```

...

```
<div id="sign_up"> {% block extension1 %} 
    </form action="/account/sign_up/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }} <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </form> {% endblock %}
</div>
```

If I hit the 'Sign up' button just nothing happens. What basic thing am I missing. I would appreaciate a tiny lesson about this. Thanks.

Comment: Your opening form tag begins with a slash. If that's just a typo here, can you post the content of `request.POST`?

Comment: can you add your models?

Comment: The typo actually did it. No idea how it came to be there. Thanks for your help. Really appreciate.